# Prepare jpg image data for deep learning?

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, jpeg, deep-learning

I have collected images for 3 categories in jpeg format. What are steps should I follow so that I can apply deep learning techniques?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you prepare your data for building a model depends, to some extent, on the framework you plan to use. If you plan to use Tensorflow, then I'd highly recommend you look through their examples on fine-tuning:

- https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining

I'm not sure what other advice I can provide due to lack of detailed information in your question.